# How to change border thickness on a Polygon in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple polygon in Tableau Desktop. I know you can easily change the color of the border but there seems no way to change the thickness.

My shape looks like:

[image]

Then when you click on 'Color'. You can click on the Border drop down and select the color but not the thickness. Is there another way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dual axis

[image]
Put the field you have on the column shelf on the column shelf twice to get 2 side by side graphs. On the marks card, select the second mark, and change the mark type to line. Adjust color and size to suit.

On the column shelf, right click on the second mark and choose dual axis and synchronize axes (by editing the second axis and checking the synch axes box). If you want to change the order that marks are drawn, you can switch the order of the fields on the column shelf. You might want to hide a header